# How many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ into $S_{n}$?

Tags: finite-groups

I would like to know how many homomorphisms there are from $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ into $S_{n}$?

If $n=2$ or $n$ is odd, I think that there are $(n-1)!+1$. I am counting those cycles of order $n$, when $n$ is odd and adding to them the trivial homomorphism. Am I right? In the general case I've failed.

I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: There are no homomorphisms from $Z_n$ **onto** $S_n$ for any $n \geq 3$, since the former group is abelian and the latter group is not.  Do you really intend for your homomorphisms to be surjective?  If not, the problem becomes decidedly less trivial...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I agree with you. There are no surjective homomorphism from $Z_{n}$ onto $S_{n}$. So, I am trying to find homomorphisms that are not surjective, since they don't exist.

Comment: Cycles of order $n$ only give you _some of_ the _injective_ homomorphisms. In general you're trying to count the number of permutations of order _dividing_ $n$, and such permutations may have cycles of any order dividing $n$.

Comment: But there is, for example, a map $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z \to S_6$ sending $1$ to $[12]$ (this factors through $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$), and another sending $1$ to $[12][345]$ (this is injective). Are you counting these?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I know (I think I know) how many homomorphisms there are when $n$ is odd or $n=2$

Comment: I’ve taken the liberty of correcting *onto* to *into*.

Comment: @spohreis: your answer is wrong. For example, when $n = 15$ you aren't counting the permutation $(123)(45678)$ even if you're only interested in the injective homomorphisms, and otherwise when $n = 9$ you're not counting permutations of order $3$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You are correct! Then my answer holds for  all prime numbers. Am I right now?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you very much!  That was wrong!

Comment: @Pete: I upvoted your comment, but now I see that it's not correct. Not every derangement of $p$ elements has order $p$. In fact spohreis's formula is correct for $n$ prime.

Comment: @Qiaochu: oops: *mea culpa*.  Indeed, to get an $n$-cycle in $S_n$, write down anything of the form $(1 a_2 a_3 \cdots a_n)$ with $a_i$ distinct elements of $\{2,\ldots,n\}$, so there are $(n-1)!$ such: soprheis is correct!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We might as well ask the more general question: how many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $S_m$? This is precisely the number of permutations of order dividing $n$ in $S_m$, which we can compute as follows. First, recall that if $G$ is a finite group acting on a finite set $X$, then the [**cycle index polynomial**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) $Z_G$ is given by
$$Z_G(z_1, z_2, ...) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} z_1^{c_1(g)} ...$$

where $c_i(g)$ is the number of cycles of the permutation $g$ acting on $X$.

**Theorem (Exponential formula):** The cycle index polynomials of the symmetric groups $S_m$ acting on the sets $\{ 1, 2, ... m \}$ in the usual way are given by
$$\sum_{m \ge 0} Z_{S_m}(z_1, z_2, ...) t^m = \exp \left( \sum_{i \ge 1} z_i \frac{t^i}{i} \right).$$

I am sure this result is well-known to combinatorialists but I don't actually know where to find a published proof; you can find a proof in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/gila-vi-the-cycle-index-polynomials-of-the-symmetric-groups/).

Now, I claim that a permutation has order dividing $n$ precisely when each cycle in its cycle decomposition has order dividing $n$. This is not difficult to see. Given that result, the sequence we want (for fixed $n$) can be obtained by setting $z_i = 0$ if $i$ doesn't divide $n$ and $z_i = 1$ otherwise. Thus the relevant generating function for the number of permutations of order dividing $n$ in $S_m$ is given by
$$\exp \left( \sum_{i | n} \frac{t^i}{i} \right).$$

For example, if $n = m = 6$ then we want the coefficient of $\frac{t^6}{6!}$ in
$$\exp \left( t + \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{t^6}{6} \right)$$

which any computer algebra system (such as WolframAlpha!) will tell you is $396$. For a larger example, if $n = m = 12$ then we want the coefficient of $\frac{t^{12}}{12!}$ in
$$\exp \left( t + \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{t^4}{4} + \frac{t^6}{6} + \frac{t^{12}}{12} \right)$$

which is $133494912$.

Comment: This is in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences at https://oeis.org/A074759.